# failed to open stream: No such file or directory composer cacert .pem file

Tags: php, composer-php, environment-variables

I trying to installing ratchet using composer I installed composer using the insteller.exe but my problem is when I run this line on CMD I get this error

```
C:\1>php "C:/programData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar" require cboden/ratchet

 [ErrorException]
 fopen(C:\Users\shako\AppData\Local\Temp;C:\xampp\mysql\bin;C:\xampp\php;/co
 mposer-cacert-300c74d6960d46715ffed607c8e36acfa7cbcad49862bb1b67d3c43dea9bf
 b40.pem): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I tryed  to fix this error by changing this line from `php.ini`  file 
from

```
sys_temp_dir = "/tmp"
```

to

```
sys_temp_dir = C:\Users\shako\AppData\Local\Temp;C:\xampp\mysql\bin;C:\xampp\php\php.exe
```

but I still get the same error

Answer (score 1):

I tried to comment sys_temp_dir but it didn't work for me.

I resolved the issue by creating a folder for temporary files outside the application folder, a location which the users don't have access to. Then I defined that folder to sys_temp_dir. As an example:

sys_temp_dir = C:\inetpub\temp\files

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Comment this line

```
sys_temp_dir
```

in your **php.ini**